# cron task to end php sessions

Tags: linux, cron, php

I have a php code (chat) which starts a session (`session_start();`). If user're clicking the "leave chat function" (logout) it kills the session.

But if user doesn't use it, it's still alive.

```
<?php

session_start();   
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){    
 
//Simple exit message
$logout_message = "<div class='msgln'><span class='left-info'>Používateľ <b class='user-name-left'>". $_SESSION['name'] ."</b> opustil túto konverzáciu.</span><br></div>";
file_put_contents("log.html", $logout_message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php"); //Redirect the user
}

 if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
if($_POST['name'] != ""){
    $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
}
else{
    echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
}
}

?>
```

I want a cron task to run and kill these sessions at midnight. I never done it before.

[image]

And now i have to select php script which contains the `session_destroy();` command.

Is this the correct way ?

Which parameters should i use ?

Comment: No, `session_destroy()` will only destroy the "current session" only. I think that [SessionHandler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php) could help.

Comment: That's typically handled by PHP itself, either with a garbage collection process randomly triggered by a request (the default) or by an OS level cron job (I've seen that in certain Linux distros). So it'd help to know why you need to code it yourself. In any case, there aren't builin functions to do it. To you need to act right into the storage backend (file system by default).